# Angular 2 circular svg with stroke

Tags: angular, css, typescript, svg

I want to create a circular svg like this 
[image]

and I found [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) library and some other libraries also. But, none of them matches my requirement. I really don't know how to create like this one. Can anyone help me how to create svg like this? Any reference/plnkr link would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it require a plugin to handle this. I did a prototype with SVG. Hopefully, it will be helpful for you. Check the code below (*I use SCSS*):

```css
$pi: 22/7;
$r: 50;
$circumference: (2 * $pi * $r);
circle {
  cx: 60;
  cy: 60;
  r: $r;
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: transparent;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.bg-circle{
  stroke: lightblue;
}

.hl-circle{
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dasharray: calc(#{$circumference} * 10 / 100) #{$circumference};
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.st-circle{
  stroke: white;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  stroke-dasharray: 2 (($circumference / 10) - 2);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle class="bg-circle"></circle>
  <circle class="hl-circle"></circle>
  <circle class="st-circle"></circle>
</svg>
```

You can check the working [fiddle here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jCtck27FLvMXdEzr3kzZ?p=info).

Comment: Thanks, @Mr_Green. `stroke-dasharray: calc(#{$circumference} * 10 / 100) #{$circumference};` // here 10 will be dynamic. any idea how to do that? can we create thorough js?

Comment: Yes pass that `stroke-dasharray` attribute through JS. check `setAttribute`.

Comment: Got it. New to SVG. I will put some effort to understand the SVG. Thank you so much :) it helped me.